# Move table cell back into the previous cell using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a document set up like this:

```css
.tableLeft {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table id="userWall">
  <tbody>
    <td class="tableLeft">
      <b>example</b>
    </td>
    <td class="tableRight">
      <b>date</b>
      <p>text here</p>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to move the second element of the `tableRight` `td` so it looks as if it were in the first column. I need to do this with CSS only as I do not have access to modifying the DOM (custom CSS on another site). What I'm hoping it would look like is this: (if I wasn't clear)

```css
.tableRight {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table id="userWall">
  <tbody>
    <td class="tableLeft">
      <b>example</b>
      <p>text here</p>
    </td>
    <td class="tableRight">
      <b>date</b>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is it for this particular case of this basic example hide a more generic one. We can always find hacks for particular cases but difficult for generic ones

Comment: Hello, I haven’t tried it but you can give it a try: give the table ‘tbody tr’ style ‘display:flex’ and just give the ‘td.tableRight’ the property ‘order:1’ and the left one the order:2;... not sure if this works at all but tell me if it does 

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi not sure about flex, but grid piling elements in the same cell might be the funny trick he was looking for : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZEWmmeY ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, yes I said I am not sure about it, but I just gave a test and it does work perfectly as desired, anyway lets wait for her to tell us what she used and how did it impact on her code :)